# Enable & Disable Log-watch feature in Linux server

Tags: logwatch

Can anyone please share the procedure how to enable & disable the log-watch feature in Linux RHEL 5 machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Logwatch is usually started by cron.

Check directory /etc/cron.daily/ for a script which launches logwatch.

In RHEL there is a symlink `/etc/cron.daily/0logwatch` which points to `/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/logwatch.pl`

You can remove this link (0logwatch) from /etc/cron.daily to prevent logwatch from running every day:

```
rm /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch
```

To enable it back just create a symlink again:

```
ln -s /usr/share/logwatch/scripts/logwatch.pl /etc/cron.daily/0logwatch
```

Comment: I am looking for enable procedure of log-watch in RHEL5.How to enable the log-watch.what is the exact procedure,need to follow to enable the log-watch.